# How to play a video from Amazon S3 in Android App?

Tags: android, video, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, bytearrayoutputstream

I use   `aws-android-sdk-1.4.3/samples/S3_SimpleDB_SNS_SQS_Demo` to preview my files stored on Amazon (Amazon Simple Storage Service). Looking through code I saw that they use this, to acces the files:

`com.amazonaws.demo.s3.S3.getDataForObject  (line 130)`

```
 public static String getDataForObject( String bucketName, String objectName ) {
        return read( getInstance().getObject( bucketName, objectName ).getObjectContent() );
    }


protected static String read( InputStream stream ) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream( 8196 );
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ( ( length = stream.read( buffer ) ) > 0 ) {
            baos.write( buffer, 0, length );
        }

        return baos.toString();
    }
    catch ( Exception exception ) {
        return exception.getMessage();

    }
}
```

}

Well, I have modified this methods to return `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead then I easily transform it to `String` or `Bitmap` (applying `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` then  using 
`BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte[] data, int offset, int length, Options opts)`).

So, it works on text-files and pictures. My problem is when I try to access videos. So, my questions are:

1.Using the method provided above, how could I get a video from `ByteArrayOutputStream` (`ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()`) and play it in a `VideoView` or using `MediaPlayer` or an approach... ?

2 .  Does anybody know any other solution to this problem of preview videos stored on Amazon ? (I heard that on their `sdk` for `IOS` they use URLs to access files...)

PS: Supplying the file URL and open it in browser does not make sense, because this URLs expire after a wile.

Comment: why used the (objectName) and What is objectName? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287233/how-to-play-a-video-from-amazon-s3-in-android-app#new-answer?newreg=e2813435b7ed4f5abb91f5718d7f133d

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First we have to provide the name of our bucket and the object (see `aws-android-sdk-1.4.3/samples/S3_SimpleDB_SNS_SQS_Demo` for a complet guide) we want to open then get the URL to our object:

```
    AWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("YOUR_AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "YOUR_AMAZON_SECRET_KEY_ID");
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(myCredentials);
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest request = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectName);
    URL objectURL = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(request);
```

Now, just play the video in a video view, supplying the URL obtained:

```
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    mediaCtrl = new MediaController(this);
    mediaCtrl.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaCtrl);
    Uri clip = Uri.parse(objectURL.toString());
    videoView.setVideoURI(clip);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

I want to give thanks to @CommonsWare for

- indicating me through `REST API` (even the code I used is from `aws-sdk` reading the `REST API` documentation helped me and show also other ways of requesting Amazon objects)
- indicating me to use `generatePresignedUrl()`
- the code for [playing the video is also inspired from his materials](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Media/Video/src/com/commonsware/android/video/VideoDemo.java).

Comment: doesnt this throw MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException happend ? beacause the url is not in the format which android player will accept

Comment: @therealprashant I don't remember at this time, was long time ago :). But once you have the url I think you can format it as per your needs.

Comment: @AlexAndro Can u pls share which sdk u used ? Using https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/tree/master/aws-android-sdk-s3 is not working

Comment: @Erum The version is specified `aws-android-sdk-1.4.3` Anyway this is realy old, I assume now there are other ways to use Amazon SDK, maybe using Android Studio Gradle

Answer (score 3):

> 1.Using the method provided above, how could I get a video from ByteArrayOutputStream (ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()) and play it in a VideoView or using MediaPlayer or an approach... ?

*Maybe* you could get it to work by publishing the byte array through a `ContentProvider` and `openFile()`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe) where I demonstrate serving a file by means of a custom `InputStream` this way.

The media subsystem is rather fussy, though, and so I do not give you good odds on this working.

> 2 . Does anybody know any other solution to this problem of preview videos stored on Amazon ? (I heard that on their sdk for IOS they use URLs to access files...)

Last I checked, S3 had a REST API that you could use to generate URLs to the videos. I'd hand that URL to `MediaPlayer` or `VideoView`.

> Supplying the file URL and open it in browser does not make sense, because this URLs expire after a wile.

But you control how long "a wile [sic]" is. Make it be 24 hours or something.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will take a look to both solutions you provided. Do you know where can I take that "S3 REST API" from ?! About the duration of the URL availability, I'm afraid that it is controlled by Amazon....

Comment: @AlexAndro: "About the duration of the URL availability, I'm afraid that it is controlled by Amazon" -- I guarantee you that it is not. I control it myself, from the Ruby API, for making my books available for download to subscribers. Also, you can see the time-limited URLs in action in things like the S3 Explorer for Firefox. You are searcing for "pre-signed URLs" in the documentation IIRC. "Do you know where can I take that "S3 REST API" from" -- you don't need it, as the Java API has `generatePresignedUrl()` that you can use for this.

Answer (score 0):

@AlexAndro answer

```
AWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("YOUR_AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "YOUR_AMAZON_SECRET_KEY_ID");
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(myCredentials);
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest request = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectName);
URL objectURL = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(request);

getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
mediaCtrl = new MediaController(this);
mediaCtrl.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaCtrl);
Uri clip = Uri.parse(objectURL.toString());
videoView.setVideoURI(clip);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

solved my problem, but it needs to define your region
using

```
s3client.setRegion(Region.EU_Paris.toAWSRegion())
```

`EU_Paris` is for `eu-west-3`

here you can find all [regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region)