# Android - Display a video thumbnail from a URL

Tags: android, url

I need to display a video thumbnail based to a **URL** into an `ImageView` view child of my `ListView` items, i have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743223/it-is-possible-to-display-a-video-thumbnail-from-a-url-on-android-4-and-above) but not worked.

**Result**

[image]

**Code**

```
        thumb_image.setImageBitmap(new LoadVideoThumbnail().execute(URLs.videos +"/"+videos.get(position).getId()+".mp4").get());
```

**AsyncTask**

```
public class LoadVideoThumbnail extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Bitmap>{

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... objectURL) {
            //return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(objectURL[0], Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
            return ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(objectURL[0], Thumbnails.MINI_KIND), 100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
             //img.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Get the thumbnail from the server that is serving the video. Otherwise, I suspect that you will need to download the whole video to get a thumbnail.

Comment: I'm just commenting as this isn't really an answer, but we use Picasso at work. http://square.github.io/picasso/ open source , easy to use and works on android really well.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes the thumbnail must be activated on the server side

Comment: Then use Picasso or Ion or whatever to download the thumbnails from the server.

Comment: use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to create videos thumbnails.

Comment: Glide loads local Videos thumbnails @hasnain

Comment: May be try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766885/glide-load-single-frame-from-video-at-specific-time/30769399#30769399 this work for me.

Comment: Hpoe this link will help for video thumbnail from url.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766885/glide-load-single-frame-from-video-at-specific-time/30769399#30769399

Comment: Hope this url is useful for video thumbnail from video url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766885/glide-load-single-frame-from-video-at-specific-time/30769399#30769399

Answer (score 12):

With glide, i am use with Glide 4.8.0

```
  long thumb = getLayoutPosition()*1000;
  RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().frame(thumb);
  Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load(url).apply(options).into(mThumb);
```

Comment: Way better than MediaMetadataRetriever solution.

Comment: Where you declare getLayoutPosition() method ?? @WallaceRoberto

Comment: Way better than MediaMetadataRetriever solution.

Comment: @karanbrahmaxatriya
--------------------------------------------------------
long thumb = holder.getLayoutPosition()*1000;
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().frame(thumb);
Glide.with(context).load(productPhotoUrl).apply(options).into(imageView);

Comment: Please explain your answer in details.

Answer (score 4):

@CommonsWare,

This is not the case that for every video store individual thumbnail in server. but we have some library

> **fmmr.jar with using jniLibs**

which directly provide the thumbnail from server url with in 10 second.

The [sample code](https://github.com/Tejas-Chauhan/VideoThumbnailFromURL) for Thumbnail.

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever fmmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
        try {
            fmmr.setDataSource(videoPath);

            Bitmap b = fmmr.getFrameAtTime();

            if (b != null) {
                Bitmap b2 = fmmr.getFrameAtTime(4000000, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
                if (b2 != null) {
                    b = b2;
                }
            }

            if (b != null) {
                Log.i("Thumbnail", "Extracted frame");
                return b;
            } else {
                Log.e("Thumbnail", "Failed to extract frame");
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            fmmr.release();
        }
```

Comment: this library size is too large, because wrote in native, about 25MB!

Answer (score 1):

Hello try this snippet working in my case

```
        Uri videoUri = data.getData();
        String selectedPathVideo="";
        selectedPathVideo = ImageFilePath.getPath(getApplicationContext(), videoUri);
        Log.i("Image File Path", ""+selectedPathVideo);

        try {
            Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(selectedPathVideo, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);


            imgFarmerVideo.setImageBitmap(thumb);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The support class

```
public class ImageFilePath {
    /**
     * Method for return file path of Gallery image
     *
     * @param context
     * @param uri
     * @return path of the selected image file from gallery
     */
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri)
    {

        //check here to KITKAT or new version
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use android ThumbnailUtils class

```
  public static Bitmap getThumblineImage(String videoPath) {
    return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoPath, MINI_KIND);
  }
```

Comment: import static android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND;

Answer (score 1):

Below is Kotlin code to get thumbnail from the video path.

```
fun retrieveVideoFrameFromVideo(videoPath: String?): Bitmap? {
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
    var mediaMetadataRetriever: MediaMetadataRetriever? = null
    try {
        mediaMetadataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, HashMap<String, String>())
        bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.frameAtTime
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        mediaMetadataRetriever?.release()
    }
    return bitmap
}
```

Call method as below.

```
val bm = retrieveVideoFrameFromVideo(model.FilePath)
imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bm)
```

Comment: I get an error: `getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Glide to load the thumbnail of video web URL.

```
  Glide.with(binding.getRoot().getContext())
                        .load("https://www.example.sample-mp4-file.mp4")
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .into(binding.ivThumbnail);
```

Answer (score -3):

To display a bitmap preview of a video, just set the video path of the VideoView and let the stream buffer.

For example:

```
videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/myawesomevideo.mp4");
```

In a few seconds you will see the first frame of the video.

Comment: setVideoPath accepts also HTTP URLs! Just replace the path in my answer with the real HTTP URL.

Comment: Excuse me  .. but also i m looking to display it into an ImageView

Comment: Why you need to display the preview in an ImageView when the VideoView itself gives you the preview?

Comment: so you suggest to me to use videoview with listview ?

Comment: Sorry, i don't get it. I never talked about WebView: WebViews are for HTML content, not video content.

Comment: sorry i mean VideoView