# How to get frame of stream video link with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

in my android TV application, at start i want to show a frame of my each stream links. my current solution is using LoaderManager and the problem of this technique is to it's too slow(application crashed).

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever to load and set video stream link.
this.retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
Bitmap bitmap = null;
retriever.setDataSource(this.mSelectedStream.getStreamUrl());
bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime();
drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
retriever.release();
```

i found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766885/glide-load-single-frame-from-video-at-specific-time) that explain that glide can used to load image from video links.

```
BitmapPool bitmapPool = Glide.get(getApplicationContext()).getBitmapPool();
                int microSecond = 6000000;// 6th second as an example
                VideoBitmapDecoder videoBitmapDecoder = new VideoBitmapDecoder(microSecond);
                FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder fileDescriptorBitmapDecoder = new FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder(videoBitmapDecoder, bitmapPool, DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888);
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(yourUri)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .override(50,50)// Example
                        .videoDecoder(fileDescriptorBitmapDecoder)
                        .into(yourImageView);
```

but when i used above code i get "cannot access from outside of package" error for VideoBitmapDecoder.

exmaple link = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8"

any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've used this snippet to get thumb nail out of video frames. Try it

```
 Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(media_url,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        BitmapDrawable BD = new BitmapDrawable(thumbnail);
        videoView.setBackgroundDrawable(BD);
```

Comment: it seems not working. i think i get only blank bitmap