# VideoBitmapDecoder doesn't accept int (Android-Glide)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap, android-glide

I'm trying to use the following code which I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30766885/10132533) to save thumbnail of a video at a specific time, but VideoBitmapDecoder doesn't accept int parameter. It only accepts Context or BitmapPool. What should I do?

```
BitmapPool bitmapPool = Glide.get(getApplicationContext()).getBitmapPool(); 
int microSecond = 6000000;// 6th second as an example 
VideoBitmapDecoder videoBitmapDecoder = new VideoBitmapDecoder(microSecond); 
FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder fileDescriptorBitmapDecoder = new FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder(videoBitmapDecoder, bitmapPool, DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888); 
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()) .load(yourUri)
  .asBitmap()
  .override(50,50)//
  .videoDecoder(fileDescriptorBitmapDecoder)       .into(yourImageView);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Root cause:** From Glide v4 they changed APIs so I will give you 2 options to solve your problem.
**Option 1:** Keep the current code and change Glide dependencies version in `app.gradle` file.

```
// implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
// annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:3.8.0'
```

**Option 2:** Keep the current Glide dependencies in `app.gradle` file and change your code.

```
int microSecond = 6000000;// 6th second as an example
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().frame(microSecond).override(50, 50);

Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
        .asBitmap()
        .load(videoUri)
        .apply(options)
        .into(yourImageView);
```

**Update:** If you want to process bitmap not display on a view

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(videoUri)
                .apply(options)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        // TODO: Process your bitmap here
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .submit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't have `asBitmap()` method!

Comment: @Javad see my updated answer, just change the order of asBitmap method.

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot it's working now. Just one more question, I don't want to show this thumbnail in an image view. I want to save its bitmap in an array list. What is the method to do this?

Comment: Thanks dude it saved a lot of time for me