# How to create thumbnail of video url form server

Tags: java, android, video, thumbnails

How to create image/thumbnails of url video form server

and I try is  not work (not show thumbnails)

```
String  String url = "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4";

     Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(url,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

    Glide.with(context).load(thumb).asBitmap()
    /*.override(convertDpToPx(100), convertDpToPx(100))*/
    .placeholder(R.drawable.camera)
    .override(200, 200)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(img_view) {
     protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
    RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
    //circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
    img_view.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
       }
    });
```

> I get slove it by answer1 !

but it get some problem about thumbnails ,it's change color is stange.

example

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522124/android-display-a-video-thumbnail-from-a-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to Generate a thumbnail from a video url in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954894/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-in-android)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this Create new `AsyncTask` like this

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = (ImageView ) bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;
        MediaMetadataRetriever mMRetriever = null;
        try {
            mMRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                mMRetriever.setDataSource(urls[0], new HashMap<String, String>());
            else
                mMRetriever.setDataSource(urls[0]);
            myBitmap = mMRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        } finally {
            if (mMRetriever != null) {
                mMRetriever.release();
            }
        }
        return myBitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Than call this `AsyncTask` like this

```
   new DownloadImage(YourImageView).execute("Your URL");
```

**EDIT**

Or you can also use [**`Glide`**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to create thumbnail of video from url

```
 RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
 requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_card_view);
 requestOptions.error(R.drawable.placeholder_card_view);


  Glide.with(getContext())
       .load(path)
       .apply(requestOptions)
       .thumbnail(Glide.with(getContext()).load(path))
       .into(ivVideoThumbnail);
```

Comment: RequestOptions is not found.

Comment: @NileshRathod what is the variable "path" in DownloadImage class, u haven't declared that.

Comment: @KJEjava48 its url of video

Comment: @NileshRathod How should i get that in this background task.If i used variable "urls" i getting error

Comment: @KJEjava48 `If i used variable "urls" i getting error ` What error?

Comment: @NileshRathod variable urls not suite there, it should be a string variable.How to get the path from urls.Is this an array??should i use urls[0] something like here??

Comment: @NileshRathod Its working but too slow. You should change path to url[0].Also what is RequestOptions here

Comment: @KJEjava48 it will take some time to load image from url and about [`RequestOptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481756/glide-4-0-0-missing-placeholder-error-glideapp-and-does-not-resolve-its-method/45481844#45481844) it new change in `Glide V-4`

Comment: so i should use glide 4 instead of 3

Comment: @KJEjava48 you should use latest version https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: @NileshRathod what is placeholder_card_view?

Comment: @KJEjava48 drawable image

Comment: Its taking too much time to load thumbnail.

Comment: Yes, I am using glide. I have uploaded video on FirebaseStorage. I want to get Thumbnail from download url of that video, @NileshRathod

Comment: Can anyone comment on the performance and impact. Is there any additional time or data overhead over image.

Answer (score 0):

```
inner class LoadVideoThumbnail : AsyncTask<String, Any, Bitmap>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg objectURL: String): Bitmap {
        //return ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(objectURL[0], Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        val m = MediaMetadataRetriever()
        m.setDataSource(objectURL[0], HashMap<String, String>())
        var bm = m.getFrameAtTime(-1)
        var decoded: Bitmap? = null
        if (bm != null) {
            val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 20, stream)
            decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()))
        }
        return decoded!!

    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Bitmap) {
        //img.setImageBitmap(result);
        Glide.with(this@EditItemsBaseActivity).
                load(result)
                .listener(object:RequestListener<Bitmap, GlideDrawable> {
                    override fun onException(e: java.lang.Exception?, model: Bitmap?,
                                             target: Target<GlideDrawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                        progresBar!!.visibility = View.GONE
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: GlideDrawable?, model: Bitmap?, target: Target<GlideDrawable>?, isFromMemoryCache: Boolean, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                        progresBar!!.visibility = View.GONE
                        return false
                    }

                }).
                into(videoImageView)

    }

}
```

LoadVideoThumbnail().execute(videoUrl)