# Set thumbnail to an Intent for VideoView

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have to play a video in one of my screens of Android and I am using Video View intent for the same. The video gets played but there is no thumbnail appearing on the launch of the screen.

My code is like this

```
@OnClick(R.id.icon_play)
    protected void playVideo(){
        String videoUrl="https://someUrl/Video/v07.mp4";
        if(!videoUrl.isEmpty()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videoUrl));
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoUrl), "video/mp4");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

By thumbnail, I mean that when the screen is launched each video should have an image of its own. (something like YouTube)

I tried `seekTo()` for attaching the thumbnail, but it didn't work. 
Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/44943830/7666442

Comment: Have your tried using Bitmap and/or ThumbnailUtils?

Comment: No, I haven;t tried those @Nero

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create thumbnail of video url form server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943575/how-to-create-thumbnail-of-video-url-form-server)

Comment: for that you have to put a your VideoView together with ImageView inside FrameLayout with same dimension. after you have to hide the imageview when video start playing . for image you can use any method..i use as answer below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem using `MediaMetaDataRetriever`.

The code goes like this-

```
public static Bitmap retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)
            throws Throwable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
        try
        {
            mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
            else
                mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
            //   mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
            bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(-1,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Throwable(
                    "Exception in retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)"
                            + e.getMessage());

        }
        finally
        {
            if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null)
            {
                mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Note that : Because my video link was in the form of server URL, that's why createThumnailUtils was returning a null when video Url was passed through it.

The below code works fine when the video is coming from local storage.

```
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("URL", MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

BitmapDrawable bitmapD = new BitmapDrawable(thumbnail);
VideoView.setBackground(Drawable bitmapD);
```

Hope this helps someone!!

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at another example. Not 100% sure if it's going to work but worth a try.

```
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("URL", MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

BitmapDrawable bitmapD = new BitmapDrawable(thumbnail);
VideoView.setBackground(Drawable bitmapD);
```

Please note, I have written this over phone so there might be spelling errors.
Let me know if this works or if you find another alternative

Comment: I tried this but BitmapDrawable is deprecated now! Is there an alternative for this?

Comment: Did some research and yes, it was deprecated. Try BitmapDrawable bitmapD = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), thumbnail);

Comment: Yes, I used that only

Comment: Bitmap thumb= ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoUrl, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        BitmapDrawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),thumb);
        mVideoview.setBackground(drawable);

Comment: Have you tried mVideoview.setBackground(Drawable drawable); as the original answer stated?

Comment: set background only, no thumbnail is appearing on the screen @Nero

Comment: It's returning null @Nero

Comment: it is returning null @pskink

Comment: yes I am passing the right URL as it the video is getting played

Comment: I am setting the image before the onClick function

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. Paste the URL

Comment: I cannot paste the URL as it is confidnetial but you can try it with any random youtube link

Comment: @Aayushi try  to load thumbnail using glide like this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/44943830/7666442

Answer (score -1):

this may be used i am using this method for thumbnail image of video on my list view of video player..

```
     Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?",
            new String[]{localItem._display_name}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    long ids = cursor.getLong(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));

    ContentResolver crThumb = mContext.getContentResolver();
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
    Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
            crThumb, ids, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
            options);
    itemHolder.thumbImage.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
    curThumb = null;
    cursor.close();
```

try this way it may be helpful

above ans is now deprecated.
new updated answer with fast one solution 
we just have to give the video data path

```
    Bitmap bmThumbnail;
    bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(arraylist.get(i)._data, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    itemHolder.thumbImage.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

where arraylist.get(i)._data => path of video.

and best way is to use Glide or any other image lodging async library for smooth scrolling of listview.