# Thumbnail for video from server not getting displayed in ImageView

Tags: java, android

Need to generate thumbnail from video stored in server, below is my code but "path" variable is giving problem, how to get it resolved. If i remove path parameter with url parameter then i am getting the thumbnails but not in proper order or sometimes same thumbnail is generated for 2 or 3 videos, below is my code -

```
Video video = mVideos.get(position);
            //play video using android api, when video view is clicked.
            url = video.getVideoUrl(); // your URL here
            Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);

            new DownloadImage(holder.videothumbView).execute(url);




public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = (ImageView ) bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = null;
            MediaMetadataRetriever mMRetriever = null;
            try {
                mMRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                    mMRetriever.setDataSource(path, new HashMap<String, String>());
                else
                    mMRetriever.setDataSource(path);
                myBitmap = mMRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


            } finally {
                if (mMRetriever != null) {
                    mMRetriever.release();
                }
            }
            return myBitmap;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create thumbnail of video url form server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943575/how-to-create-thumbnail-of-video-url-form-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a thumbnail for a video? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646361/how-to-display-a-thumbnail-for-a-video-android)

Comment: **BitmapDrawable is not deprecated**, use it like this `BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), thumb);`

Comment: **ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()** works for local  path only. Use the link above posted by Nilu.

Answer (score -1):

All the network related task must be done in a separate thread. You can't do it in main thread. You can use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) image library. It is open source and you can show different image for different state like loading, error etc.

```
Picasso.with(context) // your activity of other context referance
.load(video.getVideoUrl())
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)  // this will show during image loading from network
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)  // error image to display
.into(holder.videothumbView);
```